# Where to put the enclitic -ne?

Tags: conjunction, enclitic, interrogative, particle

The enclitic particle *-ne* can be used to form a binary (yes/no) question.
I would like to know how attaching it to different words changes the meaning of the question.
I have a clear idea of how it should behave, but that may well be because this is exactly how the Finnish enclitic *-ko/-kö* works, so I want confirmation from someone without a Finn's bias.

This is my idea:

> **The question concerns the word *-ne* is attached to.**
>   For example, consider these questions related to *Gaius cum Marco loquitur*:
>
> 1. ***Loquitur***ne Gaius cum Marco? — Does Gaius **speak** with Marcus? (The question is whether speaking takes place.)
> 2. ***Gaius***ne loquitur cum Marco? — Is **Gaius** the one who speaks with Marcus? (The question is whether Gaius is the one who speaks.)
> 3. *Cum **Marco**ne loquitur Gaius?* — Is **Marcus** the one Gaius speaks with? (The question is whether Marcus is the one spoken to.)
>
> (For some reason I prefer to put the word with *-ne* towards the beginning of the sentence.)
>   It is most common to attach *-ne* to the predicate, and it does change the meaning to put it elsewhere.
>   Here is another set of examples:
>
> 4. ***Legis***ne librum bonum? — Are you **reading** a good book?
> 5. ***Bonum***ne librum legis? — Is the book you are reading **good**? Or maybe: Are you reading a **good** (with emphasis) book?
> 6. ***Librum***ne bonum legis? — I don't seem to be able to parse this as naturally. Perhaps: Are you reading a good **book** (emphatically, as opposed to watching a good movie)?

Comment: I think you're right, though "cum Marcone...?" strikes me as awkward.

Comment: I can only think of examples where _-ne_ is attached to the first word, either a verb, or the adverb _non_ (as in _nonne_).

Comment: Pinkster 2015 addresses this question on pp. 323-326, with lots of examples.

Comment: @AlexB. A summary of those pages would be great. The grammars I have access to don't discuss this at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your idea is correct.

[Lewis-Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dne2) is not terribly clear:

> added in a direct question, as an interrogation mark, to the first or principal word of the clause

but, if you know German, [Georges](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/ne+%5B3%5D) is much clearer: *‑n(e)* is attached to the focus of the question, therefore *mostly* at the beginning of the sentence.

To answer your question completely, a quotation from [Terentius, Phormio, v.851](http://www.mqdq.it/public/testo/testo/ordinata/pf253897) is very interesting: *Sed isne est, quem quaero an non?*

- It shows *‑ne* attached to the word asked about, instead of the verb: *is it he?*
- It is an example of what can precede the *ne*-marked word in direct questions: connectives and such stuff, not real constituents.
- It reminds us that  alternatives can be introduced by *an;* sometimes *‑ne* is repeated instead.

If you read on at the Georges link, you see that, when used as a conjunction in indirect questions, *‑ne* can be attached to words in whatever position; however this is not the case for direct questions.

In particular, I have strong doubts about your *cum Marcone:* I couldn't find a single example of a prepositional phrase Prep+Noun+ne, and I would say it is impossible: the forms justified by the extant corpus are *Nonne cum Marco?* (confirmation expected) or *Num cum Marco?* (denial expected).

*Mecumne loqueris?* does work and is OK with me, even if I could find it only in modern exercise books, but here *‑cum* works as a suffix, almost a case ending, and it is a construction closer to *mihine* than to the PP above. Possibly even *magnone cum gaudio* could work, but I couldn't find any examples. I don't know what prevents enclitics to be attached to nouns *after* prepositions: but I'd bet the same holds for *‑que* and *‑ve* as well.

A difference with Finnish (I think: please correct me if I'm wrong) is that *‑ko/‑kö* is used exclusively and obligatorily in yes/no questions, while *‑ne* is not obligatory (at least in later periods) and can sometimes (rarely) be attached to interrogative adverbs and pronouns: see the above links for examples.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. The Finnish *-ko/-kö* is not always used in a strictly binary manner, but some argue that any deviation is ungrammatical. For example, "paljon" (much) in questions often becomes "paljonko" instead of "kuinka/miten paljon" (how much) and "kauan" (for a long time) is similar. The Latin analogue of this phenomenon would be replacing *quam diu* with *diune*. It is true that *-ko/-kö* is flexible and can be attached almost anywhere, so it is good to know that *-ne* is more restricted.