# What does "Filiane" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification

I am learning Latin from [Collar and Daniell's *FIRST YEAR LATIN*](https://archive.org/details/collardaniellsfi00collrich). In *LESSON IV: THE GENITIVE CASE TO DENOTE POSSESSION*, an exercise is given (sentence translation).

Some examples:

- *Līberatne? Līberō, portāmus.* (Hopefully translates to *Is he freeing? I am freeing, we are bringing.*)
- *Fīliās incolārum līberant* (*They are freeing the daughters of the inhabitants.*)

**But**, there is one sentence I do not understand:

*Fīliane Galbae litterās exspectat?*

I have no idea what *Fīliane* means. I have checked it in several dictionaries, including Lewis and Short, to no avail.

From what I have read, *fīlia* means daughter, but it has a *-ne* ending added to it? (To a noun? What?!)
My only guess is, this is a mistake and the sentence should be this instead:

*Fīlia Galbae litterās exspectatne?* - hopefully: *Is Galba's daughter expecting some letters?*

Is that correct?

Comment: The -ne is an enclitic, it's used to ask a yes/no question, and it's on the word where the question is (usually the verb, but not always), with "expectat + ne" alone = you would have: Is he/she/it wait for/expect. The enclitic can also be on noun (but it's less usual). "Filiane" alone would be something like "is it the daughter who...", putting the yes/no question specifically on this word. See here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/search?q=enclitic

Comment: See also: [Where to put the enclitic -ne?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2781/79)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your analysis is correct: this is *fīlia* "daughter" + *-ne* "?".

The trick is, *-ne* can attach to **any word**, not just verbs. In fact, it usually attaches to either the *first* word, or the *most emphatic* word, whatever that might be. Since *nōn* often comes at the beginning, *nōn-ne* became common enough that you'll often see it analyzed as a word of its own, rather than a combination! Similarly, *satis-ne* is common enough that it's often contracted to *satin'*.

So your translation is spot-on: "is Galba's daughter expecting some letters?"

Comment: Ironically, _nonne_ was just introduced to me in Cap. VII of LLPSI, although by this point in the book I've already seen _-ne_ attached to various different words.