# "Which came first: the chicken or the egg"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

"Which came first, the chicken or the egg" is a common idiom in English. It's used when you want to describe a paradoxical situation where it's ambiguous which of two related things came first.

How would this best be expressed in Latin?

My initial thought is something like:

> Utrum primum fuit: pullus aut ovum?

Is *sum* the right verb? Should it possibly be something like *venio*, or even the two together: *Utrum primum esse veni*?

Answer (score 12):

Well, you can just use the formulation of Macrobius:

> Ovumne prius fuerit, an gallina

> Ovumne prius exstiterit, an gallina

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this question for the grammatical point that gives a correct answer: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/where-to-put-the-enclitic-ne